# In RxJS 6, how can I skip the tap() part of the stream if an error is caught

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have the following code in which I want the part inside the call to tap() to only be processed if there is no error, meaning the catchError() part was not invoked:

```
myObservable$.pipe(
  switchMap(a => of(this)),
  catchError((err: any) => {
    // Handle error here
  }),
  tap(result => {
    // I want to skip this code if error
  })
);
```

How can I skip the code inside the tap () part of the stream?  Is this possible, or is tap() just not designed that way?

Comment: Put tap() before catchError()?

Comment: lol, that was it.  Thanks, @JBNizet